# A way to store keys in a dictionary without storing the key?

Tags: c#, algorithm, dictionary, hash, hashcode

For example, if writing a dictionary class, collisions are rare, but they do exist. As a result, you need to store the key to make sure that when you find your key in the hashtable, it is the right one and not a collision.

Sometimes the keys are long and they're usually strings, so each key can be over 40 bytes, compared to if it was just a hash code. What if the key stored was the object hashed but using a slightly different hashing algorithm, with different prime numbers? Then the chances of a collision would be `(1/(2^32)) * (1/(2^32))`.

You can even have another hashing algorithm and store that hash instead, so the chances of a collision would be `(1/(2^32)) * (1/(2^32)) * (1/(2^32))`. Obviously a collision could STILL happen, but the chances are so low, and you save so much memory by only having to store a 4 bytes for a key instead of over 32 bytes.

I guess this is still not acceptable though, right, because there's still a CHANCE, but there's also a chance someone's RAM could accidentally flip a bit and bluescreen, and this just seems so unlikely it's tempting not to implement. Are there any alternatives or is the small chance still not worth it?

Comment: The point of a key in a `dictionary` is that you have a known unique indexer and you want to find the value stored at that index.  If you have some off-the-wall hash that you can only get from the object itself, you probably don't need a dictionary, just a list.

Comment: If your hash is 32 bits, the probability of collision will be quite higher than 1/2^32. And you will need 4 bytes for each such hash function, so 12 bytes for 3 of them. It's not at all unlikely to happen with such small hashes, so if you must absolutely avoid collisions, I suggest you spare the 40 bytes.

Comment: You're also assuming a perfect hash function with a perfectly distributed probability of every value, which is basically never the case in reality.

Comment: Even if you had store 6 hashes, each calculated with different prime numbers, it's still less memory used than a string key hash, and the probabilities of a collision would be close to 1 in 10^50. I know there's still a chance and hashing isn't perfect but it seems tempting..

Comment: No, it wouldn't be in 1 in 10^50. Where are you getting these numbers? It would be a lot more likely than that in practice, depending on the actual algorithms used for the hashes.

Comment: This is sort of how a HashSet works.

Comment: @IVlad: I'm getting the number from a hash being a 32-bit answer and with six different hashing algorithms used on the same key, and each hash stored, is around `(1/(2^32)) * (1/(2^32)) * (1/(2^32)) * (1/(2^32)) * (1/(2^32)) * (1/(2^32))`, or `1.59 × 10^-58` Obviously hashing isn't perfectly uniform so I took out many orders of magnitude to compensate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.

Do you *absolutely* need to guarantee collision resolution?  If so: you have to store the key, or something equivalent to it.  In some cases (e.g. small keyspace, redundant data, etc.) you can use compression or custom hash functions to *reversibly* map the key to something smaller.

If not: yes, your approach would work.  Note that, due to the [birthday paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem), the probability of collision is:

- dependent on the number of elements already in the collection; and
- higher than you think.

There's a tradeoff: now you have to compute (and compare) several hashes to find items.

Following further down this path: why have a fixed number of hashes?  You could compute one hash, and only compute the next if there's a collision; this leads to a trie-based implementation.  (Of course, you then need a reliably-distributed *family* of hash functions...)

Most of this is overkill for all but the most high-performance and/or memory-constrained applications - but it is *occasionally* useful to do things like this :)

Comment: Tries are interesting. I may have an idea based off of this.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make 100% sure there arent any collison there is no way arround checking for the key before inserting. That being said, we're lucky here because a well implemented dictionnary is exactly what you need in order to quickly find a key.

That being said, you might want to take a look at the function described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-an-overridden-system-object-gethashcode). The collision chances will be rather low

EDIT: Removed some non-sense I wrote about GUIDs...

Comment: Agreed: a GUID is a much better idea than manually combining who knows what kind of hash functions.

Comment: How would you know the key pointed to the GUID though? There's no association.

Comment: You are right, this portion of my answer was silly beyond repair. I maintain your keys are stored *de facto* and are easy to check. Let me edit this...